# Quick Look of image files very slow on macOS Sierra

Tags: finder, macos, quicklook

With Lion on my old 2012 MPB, I loved how I could scroll down through many figures or image files like .png with Quick Look on Finder. It was immediate and fast, so for comparing plots with different parameters was super useful.

On a mint new 2015 MPB, quick look of images is very slow, I have an spinning gray wheel every time I scroll down a single image. Even if that image has been already previewed several times. What is going on? Is there a way to speed up Quick Look management of image files?

PD: I had already this issue with the factory OS of my machine, El Capitan.

Thanks

Comment: Same issue, take ages on my 15" touchbar to open raw images. My 2009 MBP running snow leopard does it instantly.

Comment: It's very annoying to see how Apple's OS is degrading with time. For example, copying text within Quick Look is disabled too.

Comment: I just tried this on my iMac and it works fine. Almost instantly I viewed a .png, a .gif and a .pdf. I'm running High Sierra